# WCF Serialization DateTimeOffSet issue

Tags: wcf, xml-serialization, silverlight-5.0, datetimeoffset

While making a WCF call from a Silverlight client I am getting the error :

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
>         Message=Type 'System.DateTimeOffset' cannot be added to list of known types since another type
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.DateTimeOffsetAdapter' with the same
>   data contract name
>   '[http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System:DateTimeOffset](http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System%3aDateTimeOffset)' is
>   already present

Although I have the knowledge that this is an issue with DateTimeOffsetAdapter namespace and that DateTimeOffset instances are not serialized to XML using an XMLSerializer I have not been able to solve it for many hours. Please can somebody provide guidance on how can I track and finally resolve this issue?

Here is the full stack trace:

```
StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.CheckAndAdd(Type type, Dictionary`2 typesChecked, Dictionary`2& nameToDataContractTable)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.ImportKnownTypeAttributes(Type type, Dictionary`2 typesChecked, Dictionary`2& knownDataContracts)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.CheckAndAdd(Type type, Dictionary`2 typesChecked, Dictionary`2& nameToDataContractTable)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.ImportKnownTypeAttributes(Type type, Dictionary`2 typesChecked, Dictionary`2& knownDataContracts)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.CheckAndAdd(Type type, Dictionary`2 typesChecked, Dictionary`2& nameToDataContractTable)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerContext.GetDataContractsForKnownTypes(IList`1 knownTypeList)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.get_KnownDataContracts()
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerContext.get_SerializerKnownDataContracts()
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerContext.GetDataContractFromSerializerKnownTypes(XmlQualifiedName qname)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerContext.ResolveDataContractFromKnownTypes(String typeName, String typeNs, DataContract memberTypeContract)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at WriteObjectListToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at WriteKeyValueOfstringObjectListvK47ehkqToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
       at WriteObjectsAddedToCollectionPropertiesToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at WriteObjectChangeTrackerToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at WriteProductParameterModelToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at WriteProductToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, Object graph)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, PartInfo part, Object graph)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameters(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, PartInfo[] parts, Object[] parameters)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeBody(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object returnValue, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.OperationFormatterMessage.OperationFormatterBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriter.WriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.WriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message message, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 initialOffset, Int32 maxSizeQuota)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BinaryMessageEncoderFactory.BinaryMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SendAsyncResult.SendWithoutChannelBindingToken()
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.BeginSend(TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.SendWebRequest()
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.BeginSendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.BeginRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.BeginRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.StartSend(Boolean completedSynchronously)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.FinishEnsureOpen(IAsyncResult result, Boolean completedSynchronously)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.StartEnsureOpen(Boolean completedSynchronously)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.Begin()
       at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.BeginInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at servicePath.SLF.solutionEngine.UI.ProdMan.PortfolioService.PortfolioServiceClient.PortfolioServiceClientChannel.BeginSaveProduct(Product productDTO, AsyncCallback callback, Object asyncState)
       at servicePath.SLF.solutionEngine.UI.ProdMan.PortfolioService.PortfolioServiceClient.servicePath.SLF.solutionEngine.UI.ProdMan.PortfolioService.IPortfolioService.BeginSaveProduct(Product productDTO, AsyncCallback callback, Object asyncState)
       at servicePath.SLF.solutionEngine.UI.ProdMan.PortfolioService.PortfolioServiceClient.OnBeginSaveProduct(Object[] inValues, AsyncCallback callback, Object asyncState)
       at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InvokeAsync(BeginOperationDelegate beginOperationDelegate, Object[] inValues, EndOperationDelegate endOperationDelegate, SendOrPostCallback operationCompletedCallback, Object userState)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: You should also add some code to reproduce the problem. Posting only an exception and stacktrace is not enough to provide you some help.

Comment: will this link give your some idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633923/wcf-cultureinfo-typed-datamember-serialization-communicationexception