# WCF CultureInfo Typed DataMember Serialization CommunicationException

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

When I Call my WCF service's Method with CultureInfo Typed DataMember it throws CommunicationException.

How can I solve this?

> The InnerException
>   message was 'Type 'System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar' with data
>   contract name
>   'GregorianCalendar:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Globalization'
>   is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known
>   types

```
[DataContract]
class MyClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public CultureInfo UserCulture { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this configuration to both host and clients configs.

```
<system.runtime.serialization>
<dataContractSerializer>
  <declaredTypes>
    <add type="System.Globalization.CultureInfo, mscorlib,Version=2.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <knownType type="System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar,mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    </add>
  </declaredTypes>
</dataContractSerializer>
```

> CultureInfo contains a calendar field of the base class Calendar and
>   it doesn't know about the specialized GregorianCalendar type, but we
>   would expect that's taken care of by adding the knowntype attribute.

http://www.vistax64.com/indigo/65776-cultureinfo-serialization-issue-gregoriancalendar-wcf.html